# How do I go about writing a cross compiler, from scratch?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, compiler-construction, cross-compiling

I am a Computer Science student going into my final year.

For my final year project **I wanted to do something based on compilers, and was then directed by tutors towards Writing a Cross Compiler.**

But it seems everywhere I look I'm directed towards either 'Writing a compiler' or 'This is how you use a cross compiler'

I'm looking for information to state '**This is a cross compiler**, **it was written in this language, possible ways of doing this are'**

Thanks for your help!\

Edit: Thanks for everyones help. I am now in a more comfortable position of understanding where I can start researching and produce deliverables for my project.

Comment: A cross-compiler *is* a compiler. It just happens to target another machine, not the one it runs on.

Comment: @gavlaaaaaaaa Yes, that's it.

Comment: For a student project, you probably just want to output assembly code.

Comment: Ok thanks very much for your help. And as for choosing a language to compile, which would be considered 'boring' and which do you think would be a better idea? In terms of resources available but also not being standard

Comment: @luserdroog so write a compiler which will create the back end assemebly?

Comment: @gavlaaaaaaaa Elaborate languages (like C#) would be very hard to implement and probably not worth it (without their massive libraries backing your implementation, at least). A definitely interesting language to implement (at least if you target LLVM) would be a LISP dialect. However, there's always the option of inventing your own language instead - it will force you to learn not only compiler stuff, but language design principles as well (and maybe make you see the existing languages and the design decisions of their creators under a new light).

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis I see, do you think targeting LISP considering I haven't looked at it before would be ok? Or making my own language. I have around 2 semesters to do this, with a project report and 3 other modules per semester?

Comment: @gavlaaaaaaaa I can't tell you for sure. You can look for tutorials that implement simple LISP *interpreters* and see if it's worth your time to try a *compiler*. It depends on what you have - if the professor is giving you a lexer, for example, then a C-like language could be worth trying. If you are given nothing to start from, however, and you constrained in terms of time, then I think a language of own is the safest way to go, since you can make its syntax and its functionalities as simple (for you to implement) as you want. But in the end, it's about what draws your interest the most.

Comment: @gavlaaaaaaaa I think that outputting assembly is the obvious, normal option. But Theodoros has suggested some other quite-viable options. Outputting C might be easier to do (and more likely to be useful to others (or yourself) in the future).

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis yeah I am basically starting with nothing. With the details you have given me I think the basis of my project will be either: - Write a compiler in C to produce Assembly code. Or Write a compiler in C to compile my own language. **Right lines?**

Comment: @gavlaaaaaaaa Both are definitely feasible. Note that your compiler (as a program in and of itself) can be written *in any language* you're comfortable with (regardless of what the source language and target platform are). So you can write the compiler in Java/Python/Ruby/AnyRelatedOrUnrelatedLanguage (and still make it read C/Lisp/YourLanguage, process it and emit C/Bytecode/Assembly). Since you have freedom of choice on the matter, choose whatever makes you feel most comfortable in all aspects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very broad question, to be honest. But to start tackling it, a "cross compiler" has no essential difference from a normal compiler - apart from the fact that it targets another platform than the one it's running on. However, compilers don't usually base their output off the specifics of the platform they're currently running on, anyway, so the difference is actually nonexistent.

You haven't specified what language you're aiming to write a compiler for. Having chosen to write a compiler (and not an interpreter), I take it you've probably implicitly ruled out a few traditionally interpreted languages.

If your source language isn't C, then a good way to start would be to write a source-to-source compiler from the language of your choice to C. It's a really fun exercise and it allows you to stick with high level stuff (like lexing, parsing, function call resolving, etc) without messing with low level stuff like architecture quirks. If your output code is portable C, then you can plug any C compiler (such as [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) you want and leverage the existing targets.

Alternatively, you can aim to target [LLVM](http://llvm.org/), a very powerful and extensible compiler infrastructure, by creating a "frontend" (a compiler from the language of your choice to LLVM IR, which is a form of portable bytecode). Then you can leverage the already existing "backends" (compilers from LLVM IR to any target architecture) to produce your binaries.

If you want to produce the assembly by yourself, that's also possible. The strategy is the same as the one outlined in the two above cases, except you won't emit C, or LLVM IR, but your architecture's assembly. If you're emitting working assembly, changing it to reflect another architecture (and turning it into a cross-compiler) is trivial again.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You have given me a lot to read into and a better idea. Sorry for it being so broad, but the reason for this is because I needed a clearer idea myself.

Answer (score 0):

Look at how the gcc tool chain was/is designed and developed.  It targets many platforms and machines.  It also support a number of languages.